# displaytag surpress HTML format

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I am working on an application in Java. I need to take the formated HTML data from an object and display it in a displaytag constructed table.  However, it seems like by default, displaytag supress the formatting by escapeHTML the content so my format won't display properly.

Like I used the formatted data to highlight the matching search words in tag: `<SPAN style='background-color:yellow;'></SPAN>`.  The infomation displayed in the search result was literal syntax.  instead of the yellow background of the word.

How can I unescape the HTML so it can display the highlighted background?

I am ready tried to use the escapeXml attribute.  However, the app failed due to invalid attributes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

That's odd. As per [displaytag documentation](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/tagreference.html) XML escaping is by default disabled. Are you sure that you don't have `escapeXml="true"` somewhere in the tags?

Another cause could be that you're using JSTL `<c:out>` tag to display individual values. It does by default escape XML. You can disable it by adding `escapeXml="false"` attribute to the tag.

Comment: I did try escapeXML=false in the c:out statement; however still no help.

Comment: As everything in Java, it's case sensitive. It's `escapeXml`, not `escapeXML`.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand correctly that you want to un-escape escaped HTML code? You can do it something like this:

```
public static String unescapeHtml(final String input){
    return input
        .replace("&lt;", "<")
        .replace("&gt;", ">")
        .replace("&amp;", "&")
        .replace("&quot;", "\"");
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to do it in the jsp script instead of another class

Comment: Well you could of course use this code in a scriptlet, but that would be awful. IMHO a JSP should only display values, so I'd do this transformation in the controller class.